# Encoding list variable to flag variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I've got `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
uid | list_var
--------------
 1  | ['v1', 'v2']
 2  | ['v1', 'v3']
 3  | ['v2']
 4  | []
 5  | ['v1', 'v1']
```

And want to convert it:

```
uid | v1 | v2 | v3
------------------
 1  | 1  | 1  | 0
 2  | 1  | 0  | 1
 3  | 0  | 1  | 0
 4  | 0  | 0  | 0
 5  | 2  | 0  | 0
```

What is the best way to do it in pandas?

Comment: its not really clear what your dataframe looks like ...

Comment: There are two columns. First is a number, second is a list of strings (will correct this point, thanks). @JoranBeasley

Comment: and there will only be v1,v2,v3? ehhhh nevermind i dont know pandas well enough to tell you how to do it in pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use the `.str.count` method. Note that `df` is actually a `Series` here. If you have a `DataFrame` use `.squeeze()` first.

```
In [16]: vs = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
0    [v1, v2]
1    [v1, v3]
2        [v2]
3          []
4    [v1, v1]
dtype: object

In [18]: pd.concat([df.str.count(v) for v in vs], axis=1, keys=vs)
Out[18]:
   v1  v2  v3
0   1   1   0
1   1   0   1
2   0   1   0
3   0   0   0
4   2   0   0
```